# Numeric Matching in channel entry query

Tags: channel-entries

I've got:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="packages" dynamic="no" limit="1" sort="asc" orderby="package_order" search:package_order=">3"}
```

which should bring back a result but doesn't. The "package order" field is format "integer" but that should work shouldn't it?!

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using version 2.7 of ExpressionEngine?

I've just looked at the docs for version 2.6 and there is no mention of being able to search numeric fields with `<` or `>`, so it looks like that may have been added to the latest version only.

If you take a look at the top righthand corner of the [docs](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html) page on the EllisLab site, you can download older versions of the docs if you haven't yet upgraded.

Comment: Ahhhhhhh i did wonder about that! Cheers Mate!

Comment: No problem, I've done it myself :)